# VBA - Excel - How to retrieve photos on matching file name and place them in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet where column A has a list of product codes. I also have a folder with pictures of each product and file name of the pictures are the product code. I would like to place the picture of each product in column B beside their respective  codes. If possible, I would also like to reformat the pictures so they fit in the cell.

I don't really know where to start and any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks

Comment: 'I don't really know where to start ` ... how about macro recorder while you do the steps manually. Then read up on how to loop over cells in a range and how to manipulate strings to obtain a file name. Finally, read up on `Top` and `Left` properties of Objects (including a Cell).

Comment: What is your main need? reformat image or pull them next to their products?

Comment: My main need is to pull them next to their product. Reformating the image would be a plus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code to start. Please test it out in your side.

```
 Sub AddPictures()
 Dim myPic As Picture
 Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
 Dim myRng As Range
 Dim myCell As Range
 Dim rowCount As Long
 Dim rowCount2 As Long

     Set wkSheet = Sheets(2) ' -- Change to your sheet

    '-- The usual way of finding used row count for specific column
    rowCount2 = wkSheet.Cells(wkSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    If rowCount2 <> 0 Then
        Set myRng = wkSheet.Range("C2", wkSheet.Cells(wkSheet.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))

        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
               If Trim(myCell.Value) = "" Then
                    MsgBox "No file path"
               ElseIf Dir(CStr(myCell.Value)) = "" Then
                    MsgBox myCell.Value & " Doesn't exist!"
               Else
                    myCell.Offset(0, 1).Parent.Pictures.Insert (myCell.Value)
                    Set myPic = myCell.Parent.Pictures.Insert(myCell.Value)

                    With myCell.Offset(0, 1)  '1 columns to the right of C ( is D)
                        '-- resize image here to fit into the size of your cell
                        myPic.Top = .Top
                        myPic.Width = .Width
                        myPic.Height = .Height
                        myPic.Left = .Left
                        myPic.Placement = xlMoveAndSize
                    End With
               End If
        Next myCell

    Else
        MsgBox "There is no file paths in your column"
    End If
End Sub
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

PS: set range, file paths according to your values. If you need to search entire sheet for used REAL columns and rows, let me know. I can share a function for that. Right now you only need to find used rows in the specific file-paths column, so the above typical used row count line is good enough.

Comment: I will tested tomorrow and give you feedback. thanks bonCOdigo

Comment: Hey!!! it works!!!! Thank you so much!!! I will try to improve the code from here. but this the first that works since Friday. I was wondering where you learned VBA? I have no programming background but I need to learn it for my job. I read VBA for dummies and Excel power programming but I just learned the basics. Do you know any way I can improve with VBA online? THanks Again. you made my Day!!

Comment: I am glad you got it worked out :) I learnt VBA on the job. But I do have programming background though. However it should't matter if you put some good effort. Excel Power Programming is good to get you going. Try to write programmes on your own for past questions asked here. (start with the basic ones and make sure those questions are already answered - so you get some sort of a gurantee in validated output). For what field are you using VBA? Anyway care enough to mark up the answer, so system gets updated as well :) ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I am a sales coordinator and I am trying to learn so it simplifies my daily tasks. Thanks again. I did mark uo the answer. (I think?) If I need to do something more let me know. ciao

Comment: Good to know. If the answer is correct then it follows by the up vote. Cheers.

Comment: This inserts the images as linked pictures. Is there anyway to insert them as embedded images or convert the linked images to embedded images?

Comment: Hi, when I run this macro, it creates, as well as the desired result, a pile of images (copies of all the images in the workbook) in whatever cell is selected at  the time. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @AasimAzam what do you mean by *whatever cell is selected at the time*? In the above vba code, there's no selected cell, instead it is taking user's preferred range and iterate through each cell to insert.

Comment: @MattWeick I just saw your comment as I saw Azam's. Well for embedded images, you have to take sheetname into account. Try this e.g. `wkSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:= Shapes(myPic.Name), Address:="", SubAddress:="", ScreenTip:=""`

Comment: @bonCodigo, when I run the macro, I will get the images where ever I need it, exactly as above, however, I will also get along with it a pile (as a copy) of all the images where ever my cursor last clicked, so say my cursor is on L1, and I run the macro I get all the images there. But these images are not locked to any cell.

Comment: I assumed it was to be put into the one above, so this one goes into its own module. I'm a totol noob at this!

Comment: @AasimAzam Please see [this post to learn how to add a code into a vba module](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html). And above code is triggered using `Get Pics` command button added on the the worksheet.