# Multiple Pictures in Excel Sheet in DIfferent Cells

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Due to the nature of business, I have:

- Multiple Pictures in a Folder

I am looking for a small macro which can actually:

- Take All pictures from Specified Folder
- Insert them one by one in different cell with a fixed size in each new row

Please suggest the best way

Comment: take a look the post I did in the answer section. :) if both posts are helpful to you may mark them by voting up.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [this post for inserting pictures from a folder into your worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773351/vba-excel-how-to-retrieve-photos-on-matching-file-name-and-place-them-in-cel/13773843#13773843).

Since you only have one path name without specific image name, I suggest you to rename your pictures into a sequential name list.

e.g. Folder has 10 images
`img01`
`img02`
`img03... img10`

Then you may modify the above code to loop through based on the last two digits of the picture name.
You may set max count of for loop based on the number of images you have in the folder.

```
For i = 1 to 10
  '-- insert picture
Next i
```

Once you have tried that out, if you have futher questions you may comment. Happy to help if so.